# Rails RSpec Test Does not Pass Correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm writing model tests with RSpec for a `Cookbook` model. Each user `has_many` cookbooks, and each cookbook `belongs_to` a user. To make sure that a `Cookbook` could not be created without a user, I wrote the following test:

```
it "is invalid without a user" do
  expect(FactoryGirl.build(:cookbook, user: nil)).to be_invalid
end
```

However, when running `rspec`, I get the following output:

```
1) Cookbook is invalid without a user
   Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.build(:cookbook, user: nil)).to be_invalid
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `cookbooks' for nil:NilClass
```

So, then, to test for an error being raised, I made the test like this:

```
it "is invalid without a user" do
  expect{FactoryGirl.build(:cookbook, user: nil)}.to raise_error(NoMethodError)
end
```

However, that test also fails with the following output:

```
1) Cookbook is invalid without a user
   Failure/Error: expect{FactoryGirl.build(:cookbook, user: nil)}.to raise_error(NoMethodError)
     expected NoMethodError but nothing was raised
```

If it means anything, here is the factory for the cookbook:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :cookbook do |f|
    f.title "#{Faker::Name.first_name}'s recipes"
    f.description "#{Faker::Name.last_name}'s favorite recipes."
    f.user 1
  end
end
```

How should I go about writing the model test so that it makes sure a user is required when creating a `Cookbook`?

Comment: Please, post your Cookbook class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your model you may have some validation or before callback that calls `bookshelves` on User model. When you call `be_invalid` on your test, RSpec calls `valid?` on the object built through FactoryGirl. The object runs the validations and the error is raised since it tries to call `bookshelves` on a `nil` object (user).

When you test for error raising, it doesn't happen because `valid?` wasn't called on the object. Thus your test will raise the error if you do this way:

```
it "is invalid without a user" do
  expect{FactoryGirl.build(:cookbook, user: nil).valid?}.to raise_error(NoMethodError)
end
```

However I don't recommend you to only make that change on your test to make it pass. You should go to your model and check whether user is present before calling `bookshelves` on it. If you don't do so, your app will break whenever you try to create a `Cookbook` without a user.